# Set interval between two effects

Tags: jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I want have a flipping effect set up but I want it to keep flipping indefinitely every 3 seconds.

I have this code:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('div#front-page-mosaic .front-box.flip').find('div').stop().rotate3Di('flip', 500, {direction: 'clockwise', sideChange: mySideChange});
    setTimeout( function() {
        $('div#front-page-mosaic .front-box.flip').find('div').stop().rotate3Di('unflip', 500, {sideChange: mySideChange});
    }, 3000);   
}, 3000);
```

But it is only executing the flip and unflip once.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: does plugin provide a complete callback? Would be better to synchronize this using that callback if it does

Comment: which plugins do yo use? write in details

Comment: http://www.zachstronaut.com/projects/rotate3di/